# Height of a caption on a Figure

Tags: captions

I just want to write a long text on a caption but i got this message:
"Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while output is active".

I've tried writing less and it works, but i really need to put some extra information.

I'm actually using \usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption} for my captions.

There any way to fix it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: that (probably) means that the text (outside the figure as well as the figure) does not exactly fit the page, and that there is no stretchable white space glue to fill out the gap, but there are other causes, hard to say if you provide no example. The caption won't be involved other than it affects the height of the figure box.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried with what you say. But it was just a simple missed \protect\citeA{<label>} the reason it was not working well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a syntax error issue which was not reported or hinted at in the posting itself and was only revealed in a subsequent comment.